# People arranged in a queue probability of one standing in front of each other

Tags: probability, combinatorics

People $O_1,O_2,\ldots,O_{10}$ were arranged in a queue. Decide whether the following events are independent:

1)$O_1$ is in front of $O_2$ and $0_3$

2)$O_2$ is not in the end

I know how to calculate probability of those events separately but how to calculate $P(1 \cap 2)$? I want also to know the explanation for the formula i am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: If $O_2$ is at the end (complement of event 2), does this affect the probability of event 1?

Comment: I think it does not, but i do not understand the hint.

Comment: If $O_2$ is at the end, then $O_1$ has to be in front of $O_2$ which would affect the probability of the event (1).  This means $O_1$ and $O_2^c$ (complement) are not independent.

Comment: Understand, but what if i want to have numerical result?

Comment: $P(O_1\cap O_2)+P(O_1\cap O_2^c)=P(O_1)$.  It may be easiest to determine $P(O_1\cap O_2^c)$ and $P(O_1)$.